# How to redirect almost similar links?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to write two redirects:

1. From
   `https://site.ru/dveri` to `https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/`
2. From
   `https://site.ru/dveri?start=14` to `https://anothersite.ru/blog/`

I wrote two rules in htaccess:

#1

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dveri[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/ [L,R=301]
```

#2

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dveri[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://anothersite.ru/blog/? [L,R=301]
```

Result:

link `https://site.ru/dveri` redirects correctly to `https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/`

link `https://site.ru/dveri?start=14` redirects incorrectly to `https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/?start=14`

Answer (score 1):

The two rules you wrote are the same. Try this for the second

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /dveri\?start=14$
RewriteRule ^ https://anothersite.ru/blog/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

My experienced collegue helped me with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dveri[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=14$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://anothersite.ru/blog/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dveri[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dveri[?\s/] [NC]
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=14$
> RewriteRule ^.*$ https://anothersite.ru/blog/? [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dveri[?\s/] [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/ [L,R=301]
> ```

If these directives are placed at the top of the root `.htaccess` file then these can be simplified to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=14$
RewriteRule ^dveri/?$ https://anothersite.ru/blog/ [NC,QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^dveri/?$ https://anothersite.ru/dveri-iz-dereva/ [NC,R=301,L]
```